# How can a predefined width be set of columns by colResizable

Tags: javascript, jquery, resize

I would like to know that how can predefined column width be set with colResizable.

```
$("#sample").colResizable({
liveDrag:true,
gripInnerHtml:"<div class='grip'></div>", 
draggingClass:"dragging", 
onResize:onSampleResized
});
```

Here how can I set different width for different columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that you're using the colResizable from this website: http://www.bacubacu.com/colresizable/  If so, you can inspect their code and see that they put widths on the cells like so:

```
<table id="sample4" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" class="JColResizer">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td id="veg" style="width: 204px;"> </td>
      <td id="bread" style="width: 145px;"> </td>
      <td id="meat" style="width: 97px;">   </td>
      <td id="milk" style="width: 80px;">   </td>
      <td id="sweets" style="width: 42px;"> </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```